# Getting files with custom fields from SharePoint folder via REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Picture Library with folders within. Root folder contains another folders which named by years. Each year folder contains several album folders. And at least each album foilder contains pictures. I created new Boolean field 'IsCover' which defines cover image for album. 
Then I try to get album folders with files via REST API and I want to know which file is cover, but response does not contain such field.

```
http://portal/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('mediagallery/2016/')/Folders?$expand=Files

"CheckInComment": "",
"CheckOutType": 2,
"ContentTag": "{4E99ABFD-51A3-460F-9B34-1A1962F3C2CF},1,2",
"CustomizedPageStatus": 0,
"ETag": "\"{4E99ABFD-51A3-460F-9B34-1A1962F3C2CF},1\"",
"Exists": true,
"Length": "98331",
"Level": 1,
"MajorVersion": 1,
"MinorVersion": 0,
"Name": "IMG_3474.JPG",
"ServerRelativeUrl": "/MediaGallery/2016/NY/IMG_3474.JPG",
"TimeCreated": "2016-03-20T21:00:27Z",
"TimeLastModified": "2016-03-20T21:00:27Z",
"Title": null,
"UIVersion": 512,
"UIVersionLabel": "1.0"
```

If I try to get all items in library, that's ok, it shows me my field.

```
http://portal/_api/web/lists('guid')/Items
```

I tried to get fields with `$select` but it doesn't work.

```
http://portal/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('mediagallery/2016/')/Folders?$expand=Files&$select=Name,Files/ServerRelativeUrl,Files/IsCover
```

Comment: For SharePoint-specific questions, please see the SharePoint Stack Exchange (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: When you say 'it doesn't work', what error does it give you? I think you may have a problem with your query syntax.

Comment: @AlexChance I mean it does not work properly. It returns result but without my custom field IsCover.

Comment: If you try running just this `http://portal/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('mediagallery/2016/')/Folders?$expand=Files` without the `$select` does it return the results with all fields? If you need files and folders use `?$expand=Files,Folders`

Comment: @AlexChance It returns only standard fields, not custom. I wrote list of these fields in my first code example.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is nearly a year old but I had a similar issue with trying to find custom columns within a document library, [here](http://www.best-leaf.space/get-file-data-from-rest/) had the answer for me;

```js
   
var baseUrl = “/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(‘Pages/Landing Pages’)/Files?”;
var selectQuery = “$select=ListItemAllFields/ID,ListItemAllFields/Title,ListItemAllFields/FileRef,ListItemAllFields/Modules&”;
var expandQuery = “$expand=ListItemAllFields”;
var combinedUrl = baseUrl + selectQuery + expandQuery;
```

Just change the ID,Title etc for your column names

Thanks

Iain

Comment: This! Expanding the ListItemAllFields actually helped in my case. _/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/DocLib')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields_ is my request url now. Thank you! :)

Comment: You make my day! Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
http://portal/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('mediagallery/2016/')/Folders?$expand=Files
```

This request contrains only fields for file content type. To view fields from list item you should add ListItemAllFields to $expand parameter.

```
http://portal/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('mediagallery/2016/')/Folders?$expand=Files,Files/ListItemAllFields
```

This query will return list item and custom fields in ListItemAllFields section.